# Can't upload Sandbox Accounts in Bulk in PayPal dev

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have created a file to upload fictious sandbox accounts in bulk. But PayPal always throws an error:

[image]

I did everything required:

- The file must be encoded in UTF-16 Little Endian (However it is not said with BOM or w/o)
- The file must have a .txt or .tsv extension
- Separate each attribute in the file with Tab.
- The first row in the file must begin with a hash-mark ("#")
- The file must have at least one row of Sandbox test account data
- The file must not be more than 1 Mb in size.

File:

```
#country-code   account-type    email   password    firstname   lastname    PayPal-balance  verified    credit-card-type    payment-card

US  BUSINESS    test-biz@gmail.com  12345678    fname   lname   0   Y   VISA
US  PERSONAL    test-per@gmail.com  12345678    fname   lname   100 N   MASTERCARD  PAYPAL
```

I tried `UTF-16LE` with BOM and without. No chance. Does anybody ecperienced something similar? Does that functionality work at all?

Answer (score 1):

Saved the file in `Sublime Text 3` with the following settings and it eventually made it:

- UTF-16LE with BOM
- UNIX Line Ending (LF)

[image]

That PayPal didn't say a word about BOM and Line Endings.